# Including MMSystem.h

Tags: c++, audio, compilation, linker

I'm writing a simple C++ program, where I need to use `MMSystem.h`.

I compile it with `g++ -g .\audiodemo.cpp -o audio -lm -lwinmm`, but it throws an error

> MMSystem.h: No such file or directory

I haven't even started using `mmsystem` in my code and thought it was a standard library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <MMSystem.h>

using namespace std;

const int NUMPTS = 44100 * 10;   // 10 seconds
int sampleRate = 44100;
short int waveIn[NUMPTS];   // 'short int' is a 16-bit type; I request 16-bit samples below

int main(){
    PlaySound(TEXT("CantinaBand3.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);// - the correct code

    int test = 0;
    cin>>test;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mmsystem.h` is part of the same Windows SDK that has `Windows.h`, it is not a standard header of C++ itself. Did you install a Windows SDK for your compiler? Do you have your compiler's search paths configured properly to find that SDK's files? Also, you shouldn't need to use `#include <mmsystem.h>` manually since `windows.h` already does that by default for you.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Hmm interesting. I have't installed windowsSDK but if windows.h is part of the windowsSDK why doesn'tthat throw an error for me ?

Comment: Also, the header name is all lowercase: some systems (maybe even compilers) are case-sensitive on filenames.

Comment: I'm compiling this on Windows10

Answer (score -1):

If you are using code blocks IDE, first go to setting then click on compiler then go to Linker Setting and add **winmm** into the library section. Then it won't show any error.